# how to create custom API in new Azure Mobile Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

How can I create custom API's to get specific data in/out from SQLAZURE DB using the new Mobile Apps. I have looked at the server and client projects using the ToDoList sample app.

Comment: What language are you trying to use - Node or C#/.NET?

Comment: I am running on Node (azure mobile services) for now but for Mobile Apps I would go for .net

Answer (score 1):

The azure-mobile-apps SDK (currently 2.0.0-alpha3) supports filtering on the READ and tagging on the INSERT.  For a quick sample, check here:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/tree/master/samples/personal-table - this is a sample that implements authentication and adds another query predicate to the query being sent through to the SQL driver to implement a personal store.

For something a little bit different, you can use the table.read() function callback to use your own SQL statement.  For example:

```
// Display the event stream for the specified user (using SQL)
// Note: This script has an issue in that it ignores all query parameters such as top, skip, select, where, etc.
table.read(function (context) {
    if (context.parameters.streamForUserId) {
        var statusUpdatesQuery =
            "select users.name, status_updates.message from status_updates " +
            "inner join friends on status_updates.userid = friends.friendid " +
            "inner join users on status_updates.userid = users._id " +
            "where friends.userid = ?";
        
        context.sql.query(statusUpdatesQuery, context.parameters.streamForUserId).then(function (results) {
            context.response.send(results);
        });
    } else {
        context.execute();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both javascript and .NET example is here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-define-custom-api/

The example is using raw DB query. But really SQL Azure is just another SQL instance. You can still use EF separately or any other ORM packages on your own.

Comment: these r mobile services? I am looking for the newer mobile apps.

Comment: They are all just web api apps. Other than some sugar coated difference like how auth and ci works. The same tutorial applies.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sample at https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/tree/master/samples/customApi.

Keep in mind that the custom API implementation is really only a thin wrapper around standard express routes, it's fairly trivial to manually hook up an equivalent, something like:

```
app.use('/api/custom', function (req, res, next) { /* logic */ });
```

We will be providing many more tutorials that will cover these sorts of topics soon.